# no response from my contact form script ajax php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a form to send mail using ajax and jquery, so I have a php and javascript script however when I try to send mail from my form nothing happens, Do you have a solution ? my ajax script initially allows not to reload the page when the email is sent my data variable retrieves each ID of my form ajax send data back to php script giving a positive or negative answer here it doesn't send any answer, the php script retrieves the data and transmits it directly to the host's email address (ovh)

here my ajax script

```
 $('#send_email').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data = {
    email: $('email').val(), 
    name: $('name').val(),
    objet: $('firstname').val(), 
    message: $('message').val()
};
$.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    type:'POST', 
    data: data,
    succes: function(data){
        $('#js_alert_succes').css({'display' : 'block'});
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#js_alert_succes').css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#object').val("");
        $('#message').val("");
        }, 3000); 
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#js_alert_danger').css({'display' :'block'});
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#js_alert_danger').css({'display' : 'none'});
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#object').val("");
        $('#message').val("");
        }, 3000); 

        }
    });
});
```

and here my php script

```
 <?php
if($_POST){
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $object = $_POST['objet'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-to : $name <$email>\nX-Mailer:PHP";
  $subject="$objet";
  $destinataire="postmaster@arrowsecurite.com";   
  $body="$message";
  if(mail($destinataire,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['msg'] = 'votre email est envoyé';
  } else {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    $response['msg'] = 'votre email na pas été envoyé';
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `data` values are missing the `#`s, no?

Comment: no, i have add # in data values, ( firstname email name objet, message) ever not response from my form

Comment: You added the `#` in selectors that were missing them like `$('#email')`? What does happen? What errors occur? What is request status etc. Need a lot more debugging details than "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you solved your problem, but for debugging press `F12` and open `Network` tab, to see what your PHP code returns after you submit your form. And in PHP code i would recommend `return json_encode($response);`